# How to upgrade java version in Oracle 11g 11.2.0.1

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

The java version of my oracle database is 1.5.0_10.
How do I upgrade it to java 1.7.0_10

Thanks

Comment: There is missing a capital information : What is OS ? Also this question is more related for ServerFault.

Comment: Better to move a question to DBA.stackexchange than to close it -- it's definitely on-topic there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible; Oracle supplies a certain version of Java with a certain version of the DBMS, specially modified to run "within" the DBMS. It can only be upgraded by Oracle as part of a new version or a patch release of the DBMS.

See for example this discussion: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2300779

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the internal JVM, I believe that it is not upgradeable.